# How to call a Contract from an existing contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

Is is possible to call a Smart Contract from an existing Smart Contract?
Lets say you are an function and want to call an other smart Contract - is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the documentation under [External Function Calls](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=extends#external-function-calls):

```
contract InfoFeed {
    function info() payable returns (uint ret) { return 42; }
}

contract Consumer {
    InfoFeed feed;
    function setFeed(address addr) { feed = InfoFeed(addr); }
    function callFeed() { feed.info.value(10).gas(800)(); }
}
```

Though not an exact duplicate, this thread may be of use in creating a working example: [How to make external contract function calls from one contract to another?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/how-to-make-external-contract-function-calls-from-one-contract-to-another)